# Magento 2 - Magento 1 migration : all product links are error 404

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I am busy with another migration of Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.5,

I have managed to get my categories working, all categories show products associated to them (used `Iazel_RegenProductUrl module` for this.

However, every single product `(simple/configurable/etc)` returns with an error 404 page of Magento 2.

I am aware that `indexer:reindex` _in Magento 2 does not recreate URL rewrites` according to other resources found here on StackOverflow, there were also suggestions to run a 3rd party url rewrite regen module.

I have used the following modules:

```
Iazel_RegenProductUrl
OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites
```

First off, I decided to drop `OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites` as an option.  22000 products would take **hours with this module.**  *It takes around 15 minutes on my dev machine to generate 1500 product SKUs and their URLs*, so that is absolutely no solution to attempt further.

Running
`bin/magento regenerate:product:url` command that was added by `Iazel_RegenProductUrl` takes around 5 minutes to generate ~103000 rewrites (around 4+ each per product, based on categories).

One product example:

```
SELECT * FROM url_rewrite ur 
INNER JOIN catalog_url_rewrite_product_category curpc 
ON ur.url_rewrite_id = curpc.url_rewrite_id
WHERE entity_type NOT IN ('category')
AND entity_id = 409398;
```

[image: Product with entity ID 409398]

I need some assistance with someone that can compare data with their database, or advise which queries to run to verify data consistency.

- The `store_id` here is ID 1, I also have a store id 0 inside `store` table (and store website). *I don't know how to make sure they are configures correctly* ---- this is from the Migration Tool import result.

**Does the store_id here have an impact on why the products are showing error 404?**

This reason I am asking: it does not make sense *when I take the working category URLs into account*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(store_id) FROM url_rewrite ur;
```

**Only returns 1**.  The whole `url_rewrite` table only has `store_id 1`.

Please help me to assist in resolving / compare database tables.

#### SOLUTION

While this answer asked about database tables (specifically `url_rewrite`), the issue turned out to be another table:  see my answer regarding `catalog_product_entity and its attribute_set_ids`.

Also: If you just came here about URL rewrites: use the module I linked in the answer, and do not use `Iazel_RegenProductUrl` because it has been depecrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** The other answer from **LitExtension** relates to Magento versions **<= M 2.1**, more recent versions do not use `url_path` attribute entries for URL rewrites. (Read more information in that answer for relevance - additional information related to this issue at the end of this answer as well).

This answer discusses the issue I solved eventually.  My original question wanted assistance with comparing tables and specifically `url_rewrite` table.

#### To summarize:

**In my case the migration issue for error 404s were not the URL rewrites at all.
The issue I experienced is with `catalog_product_entity and incorrect attribute_set_id's` assigned on migration.**

My products and attribute sets were imported, but migration *did not update the `catalog_product_entity field attribute_set_id` correctly* for most of my products.  I had `catalog_product_entity` rows (almost all rows) that had `attribute_set_id x`, but in fact everything else were expecting `attribute_set_id z` instead.

*For instance:*

The migration had both `attribute_set_name AttributeSetName` and `attribute_set_name Migration_AttributeSetName` as well (All attribute sets had a `AttributeSetName and Migration_AttributeSetName` version.

The migration then attached products to `Migration_AttributeSetName` to `catalog_product_entity` but should have been using `AttributeSetName`.

#### SOLUTION

#### (Summary version)

*Please note that this information should be used as a starting point, and the queries mentioned below should be investigated with your individual case to see if your data has some additional filters required.*

Three steps are needed:

1. Create a filter of matching attribute sets with a `sourceid` and `targetid` `attribute_set_id`
2. `INNER JOIN the catalog_product_entity` table to use that filter to see which products will be updated and store it into a temporary table or view.
3. Create a loop (most likely stored procedure) that can update the `catalog_product_entity` table using the results of the temporary table/view.
   `UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET attribute_set_id = targetid WHERE attribute_set_id = sourceid`
4. (Optional - but recommended)
   Use [Elgentos Regenerate URL Module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) which will help you regenerate *all your categories/product/cms-page urls* because Magento 2 does not have this capability built-in anymore (it only refreshes on individual product save).

#### (Explanation)

1. Use this filter as reference:

This query filters out those products that have an attribute set `WHERE NOT LIKE %Migration%`:

```
    (SELECT DISTINCT(attset.attribute_set_id) AS LookupAttributeSetId, attset.attribute_set_name AS LookupAttributeSetName, 
        CONCAT("Migration_", attset.attribute_set_name) AS TargetAttributeSetName 
         FROM catalog_product_entity AS prod
         INNER JOIN eav_attribute_set AS attset 
         ON prod.attribute_set_id  = attset.attribute_set_id
         WHERE attset.attribute_set_name 
         NOT LIKE "%Migration%") ;
```

2. Then expanding on this: `INNER JOIN eav_attribute_set AS targetset` and store the information into a `View/Temporary Table`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _resultset_updatethese_attribute_setids_in_catalog_product_entity_ AS (
SELECT FilteredResults.*, targetset.attribute_set_id AS TargetAttributeSetId FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(attset.attribute_set_id) AS LookupAttributeSetId, attset.attribute_set_name AS LookupAttributeSetName, 
        CONCAT("Migration_", attset.attribute_set_name) AS TargetAttributeSetName 
         FROM catalog_product_entity AS prod
         INNER JOIN eav_attribute_set AS attset 
         ON prod.attribute_set_id  = attset.attribute_set_id
         WHERE attset.attribute_set_name 
         NOT LIKE "%Migration%") 
    AS FilteredResults
INNER JOIN eav_attribute_set AS targetset
ON targetset.attribute_set_name = FilteredResults.TargetAttributeSetName);
```

3. Then update all those `attribute_set_id` entries that are currently assigned to the `catalog_product_entity` table that were stored in the *temporary table/view* (I only managed to do this using a Stored Procedure and **looping through each row in order to get the `current attribute_set_id` and the `'target' attribute_set_id` from that result set.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity 
SET attribute_set_id = newid 
WHERE attribute_set_id = targetid (_IN THAT LOOKUP result (each row needs sourceid and targetid)_).
```

4. (Optional - but recommended)
   Use [Elgentos Regenerate URL Module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) which will help you regenerate *all your categories/product/cms-page urls* because Magento 2 does not have this capability built-in anymore (it only refreshes on individual product save).

This should update most of your catalog which should **fix error 404 *if your issue is similar***.
**NOTE: I have noticed some of my products have not been updated using this method, but ~90% of my products work now!**

### (Additional Information)

#### *Regarding `<= M2.1 and url_path`*

Just in case the other answer does not have this information anymore:

[Elgentos Regenerate Catalog URLs module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) explains on `url_path` on its readme:

> However, the use of url_path has been deprecated since early Magento 2.1 versions (see here). If you are running on a recent Magento 2 version, you can safely delete those values by running `DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_path' AND entity_type_id = 4)`

Answer (score 1):

First check your affected rows with select query in url_rewrite

```
SELECT
request_path,
SUBSTRING(request_path, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(request_path) - 1) AS col_trimmed
FROM url_rewrite
WHERE request_path LIKE '%/'
```

Update affected row

```
UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = SUBSTRING(request_path, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(request_path) - 1) WHERE request_path LIKE '%/'
```

#### Update: (2021/03/30)

#### *This answer helps for `<= M2.1`*

According to information in [Elgentos Regenerate URLs module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) referencing [Magento 2 issue 9113 (closed)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9113#issuecomment-488790088): `url_path` is not used in versions of `Magento ~2.1+`: so this answer will help those pre `<~2.1`, in my case `(M2.3.5)` I had no entries to delete (so the migration did it already?).

From the referenced module:

> However, the use of `url_path` has been deprecated since early Magento 2.1 versions (see here). If you are running on a recent Magento 2 version, you can safely delete those values by running DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_path' AND entity_type_id = 4)

From issue 9113:

> this ticket can be closed as url_path is deprecated.

Comment: I have `0 Zero` results in that migrated data set using this `SELECT`.  I have _23000_ products, none of those _100k+_ url_rewrites with your query.

Comment: Did you mean : 
`SELECT request_path, 
SUBSTRING(request_path, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(request_path) - 1) AS col_trimmed 
FROM url_rewrite 
WHERE request_path LIKE '%/%';`     - see the additional end wild-card

Comment: This returns a `request_path` with value `dimmers-switches-electricals/brightstar-ecp601-2-white-ecp601-white.html` and just removes the `last l from .html` : `dimmers-switches-electricals/brightstar-ecp601-2-white-ecp601-white.htm`.

All of the URLs in `col_trimmed` look like that then.

I tried this URL in browser, but nothing found.

Comment: Side note: The migration process of the migration tool is a mess: My migration attribute sets are **not assigned to the products**.  Ie: `Migration_AttributeSetSomeName` is not used:   Migration still added `AttributeSetSomeName` (the original attribute set from M1 db) to _all of my products_.
I have imported a product using Magmi.  Magically this product **WORKS**, and there seem to be _no difference from the URLs in url_rewrite:
I imported this product yesterday using Magmi and it works!
`light-bulbs-globes/calex-power-led-a60-gls-lamp-240v-12w-1020lm-e27-4000k-dimmable.html`

Comment: I am in the process of trying to assign products using mysql Stored Procedure to see if the products when assigned to their `Migration_` attribute sets if this will work....

Comment: Am I on the right track, what do you think?  At first I assumed its url_rewrites with the store_id, but then comparing an imported Magmi product, row entry in the rewrite tables look exactly the same.

Comment: I see that you are on the right track. I hope that the solution I gave earlier can give you direction to find the problem and fix it.

Comment: Since I had no success with URL Rewrites with the `request_path`, I built some `MySQL Stored Procedures` to update the `attribute_set_id` inside `catalog_product_entity` of the Magento 2 database _after M1 migration completed into the new database_. 
Its entirely two different issues, and this answer relates to URL rewrites - the URL rewrites technically 'worked', but because my migration (1.7 to 2.3.5) _does not attach the correct `attribute_set_id` to the product, the page always resulted in `404`.

Comment: For anyone else reading here: as one would expect, and my question originally wanted some advice about this _as I thought this issue is related to URL rewrites_, in my instance URL rewrites **was not the issue**, read more on my previous (up) comment - about `catalog_product_entity`.

Comment: More specifically, once this **error 404** is fixed by updating the `attribute_set_id` items, then recreate the URLs using a 3rd party module Elgentos: https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls.

To continue, `url_path` is not used in `> M2.1` versions anymore (read the information on the module link).  This answer will help for those that need assistance `<= M2.1`